# Problemas com bower

Tags: bower

Depois que instalei o bower e tento dar bower info angular ele dá **ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH**. Eu uso o git bash. Como resolvo isso?

Comment: Coloca o caminho do GIT na PATH.

Comment: Parece que você está fora da pasta do git tentando dar algum comando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É necessário adicionar o Git no Path do Windows.

Para funcionar, o caminho do Git deve estar em "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git", se for diferente, é necessário alterar a ultima etapa para o caminho que está.

**1 -** Clicar com o botão direito do mouse em "Meu Computador", então ir para "Propriedades". 
**2 -** Clicar em "Configurações avançadas do Sistema", no canto esquerdo da tela.
**3 -** Clicar em "Variáveis do Sistema"
**4 -** Embaixo das variáveis do sistema, tem um caminho de uma variável, deve-se clicar em editar nele adicionar o pwd do Git no FINAL desse caminho de variável:

**;%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Git\bin;%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Git\cmd**

(Caso o Git esteja em outro caminho, alterar o início)